# Play java framework Initializing variables on application startup in

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to initialise some variables on application startup in Play framework. I'm following this document http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal for doing the same..
However when I run the application I get with the command "play run" the initialization does not happen. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
import com.Constants;

import controllers.Application;
import controllers.Utils;
import play.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
  public void onStart(Application app) throws Exception {
    Logger.info("Application has started");
    Constants.data1= Utils.getMerchantToBrMapping(Utils.getMerchantName());
    Constants.data2 = Utils.getBrToMerchantMapping(Utils.getMerchantName());
    Logger.info("Loaded the Merchant To BR Map");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Application` controller is being used as the implementation for the `app` parameter in your `onStart(Applciation app)` method.

In other words you are not overridding the `onStart()` callback method that Play will call, instead you are just defining your own custom method.

It should rather be like this:

```
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;

import controllers.Utils;
import com.Constants;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Logger.info("Application has started");
        Constants.data1 = Utils.getMerchantToBrMapping(Utils.getMerchantName());
        Constants.data2 = Utils.getBrToMerchantMapping(Utils.getMerchantName());
        Logger.info("Loaded the Merchant To BR Map");
    }
}
```

note the import of `import play.Application;` and not your controller. Also note that `onStart()` does not throw an Exception. If you had added the `@Override` annotation it would have hinted at the problem, so keep in mind for future reference.

More on Global [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/JavaGlobal)

Comment: Is it possible to terminate the application startup if you encounter any error?

Comment: You could just throw a `RuntimeExeption`